# How to change the baseline of a rectangle in the tikzpicture environment in a table

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

My problem is that I'm making a table of flame test colors, but the colors on the right column have their baseline at the bottom of the square, so the ion symbols on the left aren't aligned in the middle of the square. I'm really new to TikZ, so I don't know if there's a much easier way to do this which allows the baseline to be set a lot more simply. I've looked at similar answers, but they all use the `\tikz` command and not the entire `tikspicture` environment. Here's my sample code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabular}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
            \hline
            Cation & Color\\
            \hline
            \ce{Li+} &
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \fill[red]{(0,0)rectangle (1,1)};
            \end{tikzpicture}\\
            \hline
            \ce{Sr^2+} & 
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \fill[orange]{(0,0)rectangle (1,1)};
            \end{tikzpicture}\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Caption}
        \label{tab:my_label}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Here's the output:
[image]

P.S. Adding padding to the row would also be super helpful so that the squares aren't straight up against the border above them!

P.P.S. I know the colors aren't very correct right now, but that I think I can figure out on my own.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple and rude solution:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{tabular}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|m{1cm}|}
            \hline
            Cation & Color\\
            \hline
            \ce{Li+} & \smallskip  
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \fill[red]{(0,0)rectangle (1,1)};
            \end{tikzpicture}\\
            \hline
            \ce{Sr^2+} & \smallskip  
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \fill[orange]{(0,0)rectangle (1,1)};
            \end{tikzpicture}\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Caption}
        \label{tab:my_label}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

For centering images in cells is used column type `m` from array package.

**Edit:**
Another simple solution is use of (old good) `mdwtab` package fro tabular environment and set baseline to center of current bounding box:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{array,mdwtab}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
            \hlx{hv}
            Cation & Color\\
            \hlx{vhv}
            \ce{Li+} & 
            \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
                \fill[purple!50]{(0,0)rectangle (1,1)};
            \end{tikzpicture}   \\
            \hlx{vhv}
            \ce{Sr^2+} & %\smallskip  
            \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
                \fill[purple]{(0,0)rectangle (1,1)};
            \end{tikzpicture}\\
            \hlx{vh}
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Caption}
        \label{tab:my_label}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]